# simulate the cursor keys (left, right, down, up arrows) in a content editable div with overflow: "hidden"

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, contenteditable

I am creating a library for custom scrollbars and I came across a problem when the overflow of an editable element is hidden, it does not scroll the content when pressing the arrow keys; is there any way to simulate the arrow keys so that the content scrolls as if it were `overflow: scroll`;

Comment: Could you specify more details? Perhaps you can give some code snippets?

Comment: example: when the user presses the ArrowDown key, a function scrolls the content to the new cursor position. remembering that because it is editable content, there will be elements .